# Try except statement in python execution

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Suppose I am making calls to a web api that requires a wait of 4 seconds after the limit is exceeded. Using a try except loop and the time package I can have the program pause if the exception is encountered. If I am working with pandas indices in an iterative loop, will the program pick up where it left off? Example:

```
i = 0
while i < len(df):
    try:
        df['A'] = df[i:i + 10].apply(lambda x: api_call(x['B'])[0] + 10)
    except IndexError:
        time.sleep(5)
i += 10
```

If the exception is raised on df[12], after the program has paused for 5 seconds, how do I get the program to pick up at the index that caused the exception (signaling that the program exceeded the number of calls allowed)?

Comment: That `i += 10` is supposed to be indented one level, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need an `else` block on your `try...except` code.

```
i = 0
while i < len(df):
    try:
        df['A'] = df[i:i + 10].apply(lambda x: api_call(x['B'])[0] + 10)
    except IndexError:
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        i += 10
```

This makes it so that `i += 10` only runs if the `try` block doesn't raise an exception. Otherwise the loop repeats with the same `i` value.